# help me understand Dodge code p0430

Tags: chrysler, dtc, ram, p0430

2004 Dodge Ram 1500 4.7 had a bank 1 sensor 1 code come on so I changed that sensor along w/plugs and coils, then drove about 2 miles truck started missing little.

Code now reads P0430 and seems like its running on 2 plugs. Just bogs down unless you floor it straightens out somewhat then but not much. If someone can help a little be greatly appreciated.

Comment: P0430 - Catalyst System Low Efficiency Bank 2 - Please edit you question for spelling and also to add proper punctuation so we can digest it better.

Comment: Probably a bad or damaged spark plug or wire, re-check your work.

Comment: @Moab - These are coil-on ... no spark plug wires ... though could still be the spark plug.

Answer (score 1):

P0430 could be caused by a defective O2 sensor, a catalytic convertor gone bad, or an exhaust leak in that area.

Other issues that could trigger that code are faulty or leaking fuel injectors,spark plug issues, incorrect ignition timing, defective ECM, intake manifold leaks, and apparently a very dirty air filter will do it as well.

https://www.autocodes.com/p0430.h

Are there any other codes that code help narrow it down a bit?